# I'm getting forreach error on my site after a wordpress update

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently updated Wordpress and began receiving this error.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php on
>   line 526

I run a multisite and although I can still log into my other websites' panels, I am completely unable to even log into my main site. I fear this is a compatibility issue with a plugin, but I can't even log into my panel to deactivate any. When I try to log in I get these further errors.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-login.php on line 496
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-login.php on line 512
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6029
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line
>   1252
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 932
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 933
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 934
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1265
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-post-type.php:526)
>   in /home2/apeluso12/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1268

This is the code being referred to.

```
public function add_supports() {
        if ( ! empty( $this->supports ) ) {
            foreach ( $this->supports as $feature => $args ) {
                if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
                    add_post_type_support( $this->name, $feature, $args );
                } else {
                    add_post_type_support( $this->name, $args );
                }
            }
            unset( $this->supports );
        } elseif ( false !== $this->supports ) {
            // Add default features.
            add_post_type_support( $this->name, array( 'title', 'editor' ) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: All the header notices are likely due to an error being printed out, probably that first one. The fact that it printed out an error in the first place is an issue to be dealt with, but it’s not preventing your website from working.   The issue that’s breaking things is that the property, supports, has a value in it that is not an array. Therefore the foreach barfs. To troubleshoot the issue, you need to trace back to where it’s being assigned. That’s where the root issue is. The foreach is just where it notices the problem.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, suppressing the notices might allow you to log in. Your production php.ini should be set up to log errors instead of printing them out  a quick google search will tell how to do that. It won’t fix the problem, but you may be able to at least get in.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue on one of my sites (including not being able to log in). The issue was with some custom post type code (class-wp-post-type.php is where it's being reference) I had added to that theme's functions.php, but it's possible for you it could also be a plugin. Mine was resolved by disabling all themes (except a default WP one like twentynineteen) via FTP by renaming the theme, and then I was able to log in and rectify the code.

My particular problem was with the 'supports' arg in my CPT code, and weirdly enough just moving it to the bottom of the array fixed it for me.

Edit: I have also noticed that in custom post types 'taxonomies' now requires an array, rather than either string or array. Changing my taxonomy to an array rather than string also fixed this issue for me on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Evaluation Unit

You should make sure you pass the correct values to each argument.

e.g. an empty array for taxonomies and the correct values for support =>

```
$args = array(
    ...
    'taxonomies'            => array()
    ...
);
register_post_type('your_cpt_name', $args);
```

This fixed the same errors for me.